# Make child div make parent transparent only behind child

Tags: html, transparency, css

Is it possible to make a parent element (div) inherit part of its child element`s (div) transparency ?
Making the bgcolor of the child equal to the color behind the parent (websites background in this case) is not an option because the divs are fixed and scrolling would result in a weird spot over the content.
z-index is no option because this can not magically make part of something else disappear if nothing, or something transparent, is placed in front of it.

Example of my goal with bgcolor and scrolling issue,

CSS

```
#header{ background-color: #d51a00;
 height: 72px;
 width: 800px;
 position: fixed;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#submenu{ background-color: #d51a00;
 height: 30px;
 width: 300px;
 position: fixed;
 display: block;
 margin: 72px auto 5px 120px;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
#submenu-l{ background: #fff;
 height: 30px;
 width: 10px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#submenu-r{ background: #fff;
 height: 30px;
 width: 10px;
 float: right;
 border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="submenu">
<div id="submenu-l"></div>
<div id="submenu-r"></div>
</div>
```

I may later move the left and right elements outside of the "submenu" so the bottom corners can have border-radius as well but the issue would remain the same.

I have found quite a few alternatives on StackOverflow and through Google but all would have the same issue in this case or require much more code; I was/am hoping for a cleaner solution.

http://imgbox.com/X8LC7wbi  (not allowed to post pictures yet)

Added image to show issue when scrolling; background is gray and content field is white, therefore two grey fields (part of child`s divs) are visible when content moves behind submenu field.

Comment: "Is it possible to make a parent element (div) inherit part of its child element`s (div) transparency" Not with CSS alone. Children can inherit from their parents. But you can add transparency to both elements and stack them. Please clarify your question with a demo and/or an image.

Comment: Added image. Sorry if I am/was unclear, I thought the issue was very well explained but that's probably because I already knew what I meant to say.

Comment: @NicoO Making both elements transparent would defeat their purpose. Please see the added image to understand the issue better. The goal is an outwards border-radius by hiding a part of the parent element.

Comment: Still not sure what the issue is. Do you have a page you could post and we can see the problem?

Comment: so bascially you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/4bFtt/ ?

Comment: @Poodimizer @NicoO Here is an example of the issue, http://jsfiddle.net/k2Jnd/1/ , if you scroll the white content field will move behind the (sub)menu and reveal the grey divs. I want the same outwards border-radius but without the div`s bgcolor being an issue here. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible with pure HTML/CSS. It would be partially possible with javascript thrown in, but even then it would be a pain to make it look right. Even if there was a hack you would be pretty lucky if it was cross browser compatible. This is one of those times where you should just make some pngs with transparency and throw them in as background images if you need that exact look.

Comment: @Poodimizer I was afraid that might be the case, no problem though, I will use two tiny png`s, just preferred to keep this png-free :-) . Thanks for your (and other`s) patience with my (apparently) bad description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give them both a class of semiTransparent and just set the transparency in that css class declaration?

Unless you are wanting to change this on the fly and then jQuery it up.

Not sure what exactly what you're trying to do though.

```
.semiTransparent{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```